# Android ScrollView doesn't work correctly in landscape mode

Tags: android, xml, android-scrollview

[image: landscape mode image of the app]

[image: portrait mode image of the app]

my xml code-->>

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/team_a"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:text="@string/team_a" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:text="@string/team_a_score"
                    android:textSize="56sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/three_but"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:background="#ff9800"
                    android:onClick="addThreeForA"
                    android:text="@string/three_but"
                    android:textAllCaps="true" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/two_but"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:background="#ff9800"
                    android:onClick="addTwoForA"
                    android:text="@string/two_but"
                    android:textAllCaps="true" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/one_but"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:background="#ff9800"
                    android:onClick="addOneForA"
                    android:text="@string/one_but"
                    android:textAllCaps="true" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/team_b"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:text="@string/team_b" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/team_b_score"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:text="@string/team_b_score"
                    android:textSize="56sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/three_but_b"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:background="#ff9800"
                    android:onClick="addThreeForB"
                    android:text="@string/three_but_b"
                    android:textAllCaps="true" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/two_but_b"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:background="#ff9800"
                    android:onClick="addTwoForB"
                    android:text="@string/two_but_b"
                    android:textAllCaps="true" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/one_but_b"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:background="#ff9800"
                    android:onClick="addOneForB"
                    android:text="@string/one_but_b"
                    android:textAllCaps="true" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reset"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="#ff9800"
            android:onClick="resetAll"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:text="@string/reset"
            android:textAllCaps="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The scrollView works correctly when the app is in portrait mode but when it is in landscape mode the scrollView works but the reset button does not remain in the bottom position as like as portrait mode. How can i solve this problem?
Also the RelativeLayout's attribute layout_height = "match_parent" shows a warning that it should be wrap_content. help me to solve this problem?? i'm a novice.

Answer (score 1):

`ScrollView` is not working well with `RelativeLayout` please use

```
<Scrollview> 
    <LinearLayout>
        <RelativeLayout>
        **everything else**
        </RelativeLayout>
        <Button .. />
    </LinearLayout>
</Scrollview>
```

Comment: the RESET button isn't  remaining in the same position in landscape mode as  like as in portrait mode.